# Strict Standards: Resource ID#7 used as offset, casting to integer (7)

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I am using Adodb in my website and after setting up all things, I am getting:

> Strict Standards: Resource ID#7 used as offset, casting to integer (7) in /home/linuxshi/public_html/shipper_new/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 485

I am unable to understand this line of code. The queries are functioning but I see a like printed on the main page of my site.

Please someone can help me on this?

This is the line of code starting from 478 to 489 in `adodb-mysql.inc.php`:

```
// returns true or false
function SelectDB($dbName)
{
    $this->database = $dbName;
    $this->databaseName = $dbName; # obsolete, retained for compat with older adodb versions
    if ($this->_connectionID) {
    @mysql_select_db($dbName,$this->_connectionID);
    $this->__db[$this->_connectionID] = $dbName;
    return $this->_connectionID;
}
else return false;
}
```

Comment: Would help to see that line of code and the line of code of what is calling that function.

Comment: Edit your question and put it in the question. It is not much good here.

Comment: I guess $this->_connectionID is not a number but a Resource. As the error says

Comment: Is there any way to fix it? I am totally confused and don't have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Is there no one to answer my question? :(

Comment: You could start a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really hoping you've sorted this out by now via another question on here or another web site. But hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles onto this question before others, like [Strict Standards: Resource ID#73 used as offset, casting to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22946193/728053).

The issue is that `$this->_connectionID` is resource identifier. But you're using it as shorthand in your array as an integer. To cast it as an integer you can use the following.

```
$this->__db[(int)$this->_connectionID] = $dbName;
```